# Nuxt generated pages return undefined VueX response on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, netlify-cms

Feel like I've looked at every forum post on the internet by the time I decided to ask the question myself. My brain is running on fumes so bear with me.

I've got a Nuxt project to host a game designer's portfolio using NetlifyCMS and VueX. I use the nuxtServerInit() function to populate the VueX store with the two types of content: 'prototypes' and 'design documents'. See bellow:

```
export const actions = {
  // nuxtServerInit is called by Nuxt.js before server-rendering every page
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, getters }, { $content }) {
    // Setup store with project data
    const types = ['prototypes', 'design-documents']
    let projectList = []

    for (const type of types) {
      let arr = await $content(type).fetch()
      arr.forEach((element) => {
        projectList.push(element)
      })
    }

    // Sorted by date completed
    projectList.sort((a, b) => (a.date < b.date ? 1 : -1))
    await dispatch('projects/setProjectList', projectList, { root: true })
  },
}
```

The same code is run on the index.vue page of my project to populate the 'Projects' component with the titles of the component.

The Nuxt generate function seems to correctly generate a page per project (either 'prototype' or 'design document'). When navigating to these pages from the homepage, no problems. However, in production, when I navigate to these pages by typing them into the address bar or even just refreshing the page after navigating to it, the console logs an error dictating that the respective project object is undefined.
[image: A picture of an error in the console]

I should note that I no longer have this issue in development which leads me to conclude that I must be doing something wrong before building the project before deploying it (currently I run `nuxt build` and then `nuxt generate` before deploying to Netlify where the build command is `npm run generate`).

I did wonder if my fetch/VueX dispatch code should be done on the default.vue layout file to ensure that the content is fetched on every page that the project renders but I felt like this might lead to multiple unnecessary fetch requests. *Is* there somewhere more global I should be putting this code or have I simply slipped up somewhere?

Many thanks in advance for any support anyone might be able to give.

Comment: If you're going the full static path only having to do `yarn generate` then `yarn start` is enough (will grab your `/dist` folder). `build` is for the other renderings. When you `yarn dev`, it's making a build under the hood. For the other issue, you may use a middleware, perfect use case here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware/#named-middleware

Comment: @kissu That middleware stuff looks perfect. I've not done it before so I'll give it a go and report back, thanks so much (for all your advice too, not just that). :D

Comment: Hey @kissu no luck I'm afraid. I made this middleware which you can see on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kitella1/b4fe7384d7e8b9569646fb422d19a2e7). I then plugged it into my layout.vue file but still no joy. Refreshing the page gets me the same error message. ;-;